# IIS Stuck in infinite load loop

Tags: php, performance, iis, localhost

I had been working on my IIS site with some php scripts and such things for a couple of hours, when my localhost suddenly decides to stop loading. If I try to go to localhost or 127.0.0.1 it gets stuck in an infinite loop of constantly loading.

I've tried editing the host in drivers of my computer, it didn't make any difference. I tried restarting my computer, that didn't help either. Neither does it help to restart IIS service.

Comment: Have you tried reverting to earlier versions of your code?

Comment: I can remove everything in the wwwroot folder, it's still stuck. I created another IIS website and it's stuck as well.

Comment: Check if you have set internet proxy pointing to localhost (127.0.0.1). You can check these settings internet explorer settings or at registry path [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings].

Comment: It was empty. If I change it to localhost nothing works.

Comment: You need to first decide if it is redirection loop, using Fiddler. Then if not, debug your PHP code to see if it is an infinite loop. So far the cause is not clear yet.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Try set the security settings of the directory to `IIS_IUSRS` and `IUSR`.